# Array index out of bound, but gdb reports the wrong line - why?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, undefined-behavior

I am a C++ beginner. I found a strange phenomenon. GDB can not give the line number of the root cause of error in this code.

```
#include <array>

using std::array;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    array<double, 3> edgePoint1{0, 0, 0};
    array<double, 3> edgePoint2{0, 0, 0};
    array<double, 3> edgePoint3{0, 0, 0};
    array<array<double, 3>, 3> edgePoints{};
    edgePoints[0] = edgePoint1;
    edgePoints[1] = edgePoint2;
    edgePoints[3] = edgePoint3;
    return 0;
}
```

The line 13 is the root of the problem. But when I use 'bt' in GBD, it print the line 15. Why?

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007f51f3133d7f in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f51f3133d7f in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f51f311e672 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f51f3176878 in __libc_message () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f51f3209415 in __fortify_fail_abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f51f32093c6 in __stack_chk_fail () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000556e72f282b1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffdc9299218) at /home/wzx/CLionProjects/work/test1.cpp:15
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugger diagnoses *practical* errors. Things that happen as a result of the mistakes/bugs in your code, after the very complicated process of translating source code into an actual program that the computer can run. It does not analyse C++ source for the mistakes/bugs in your code, nor is it actually theoretically capable of doing so (at least not in the general case). Here the practical error is that your buffer overrun corrupted the "stack". You only see reported that symptom, not the original cause (the buffer overrun itself).

It's a little like how if you accidentally steer your car off the road and smash it into a tree, the police know that you smashed your car into the tree, but they don't automatically know that this is because you had a stroke at the wheel, or because you were texting, or because you were drunk. They have to investigate to find out these details after the fact, using other (more indirect) pieces of evidence, such as interviewing you or performing a medical examination.

[image: Epic car crash analogy (by me)]

*(Notice that the phone flew through the broken window and landed on the ground near the tree: it's nowhere near the driver's hand — even though the cause of the crash was that it was in the driver's hand. A good policeman will realise that the phone probably used to be* inside *the car, and based on the half-written text message displayed on its screen it was probably in the driver's hand at the time of the crash. Case closed, your honour. Solution: stop texting while driving.)*

This is a fact of life with C++, which is why we need to pay careful attention to our code when writing it, so that we don't "shoot ourselves in the foot". Here you were very fortunate to get a crash at all, otherwise you may have missed the bug entirely and instead just seen unexpected/weird behaviours!

Over time, as you gain experience, you will become more accustomed to this, and get skilled at looking "around" or "near" the reported line to see what logical error led to the practical problem. It's mental pattern matching, for the most part. It's also kind of why you can't "learn C++ in 21 days"!

Some tools *do* exist to make this easier. Static Analysis tools *can* look at your code and sometimes spot when you've used an impossible array index. Containers (e.g. `array` and `vector`) can be implemented with additional bounds checking (for `at()` this is required; for `op[]` some implementations add it for convenience in debug mode). Combine tooling with experience for great success!

Comment: `std::array` can of course be implemented with additional bounds checking (in debug mode). I don't know what makes you think that `std::vector` is better than `std::array` in this regard. In fact, if I go-to-source on any `std::array::operator[]` in my code, I can see that MS does exactly that for certain iterator debug levels: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMnLV.png

Comment: @MaxLanghof LRO might be thinking of `std::vector::at`.

Comment: @YSC I'm thinking of `std::vector::op[]` in debug mode with VS

Comment: @YSC `std::array::at` has bounds checks (even in release) too. It's in the specification for it to do that... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at

Comment: @MaxLanghof I was thinking that `op[]` for `array` isn't a member function which of course is nonsense - you're right, it could do this.

Comment: I know and it matched ~"some containers (e.g. `vector`) can be implemented with additional bound checking...". I was wrong anyway ^^

Comment: @YSC: Yep not your fault to have interpreted it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

While it is true what `Lightness Races in Orbit` said, it is also true that, when you compile with debug info (i.e. using gcc/clang the -g option) the compiler emits `line information` allowing theoretically a debugger to associate *each* machine instruction with a source line number, even when compiling with -O3 where really *fancy* optimizations occur.

Said that, the explanation of why `gdb` tells you the program crashed on line `15` is simple: the *crash* really did **not** happen on line `13`. It's enough to look at the stack backtrace [I compiled your program with `gdb` on Linux]:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff7a24801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7a6d897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort,
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b9a988 "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff7b18cd1 in __GI___fortify_fail_abort (need_backtrace=need_backtrace@entry=false,
    msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff7b9a966 "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:33
#4  0x00007ffff7b18c92 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:29
#5  0x00005555555547e2 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdde8) at crash.cpp:15
```

As you can see in the frame #4, your program did **not** crash because of the buffer overflow but because of compiler's **stack protector** (function `__stack_chk_fail`)

Since that is not code written by you, but automatically emitted by the compiler precisely in order to detect such bugs, the *line information* cannot be real. The compiler just used line `15`, because it is where your `main()` function ends and, of course, the place where, if you look at the disassembly code, the compiler emitted code using `stack sentinels` to detect `stack corruption`.

In order to see the whole picture even better, here is the disassembly code (just use `disass /s main` in gdb to see it):

```
13      edgePoints[3] = edgePoint3;
   0x000000000000079e <+308>:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x50]
   0x00000000000007a2 <+312>:   mov    esi,0x3
   0x00000000000007a7 <+317>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x00000000000007aa <+320>:   call   0x7e4 <std::array<std::array<double, 3ul>, 3ul>::operator[](unsigned long)>
   0x00000000000007af <+325>:   mov    rcx,rax
   0x00000000000007b2 <+328>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x70]
   0x00000000000007b6 <+332>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x68]
   0x00000000000007ba <+336>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rcx],rax
   0x00000000000007bd <+339>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rcx+0x8],rdx
   0x00000000000007c1 <+343>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x60]
   0x00000000000007c5 <+347>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rcx+0x10],rax

14      return 0;
   0x00000000000007c9 <+351>:   mov    eax,0x0

15  }
   0x00000000000007ce <+356>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x00000000000007d2 <+360>:   xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x00000000000007db <+369>:   je     0x7e2 <main(int, char**)+376>
   0x00000000000007dd <+371>:   call   0x540 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x00000000000007e2 <+376>:   leave
```

As you can see, there are several instructions at `line 15`, clearly emitted by the compiler because the `stack protector` is enabled by default.

If you compile your program with `-fno-stack-protector`, it won't crash, [at least it doesn't on my machine with my compiler] but the actual `stack corruption` will be there, just producing **unpredictable effects**. In a bigger program, when stack corruption occurs, you could expect any kind of weird behavior **much later** than the moment when the corruption occurred. In other words, the stack protector is a very good thing and helps you by **exposing** the problem instead of **hiding** it, which is what would *naturally* happen without it.

Comment: Downvoted because not enough hand-drawn cartoons (kidding :P)

Comment: Ahahaha I liked your cartoon :-)

Comment: Worked hard on that 

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in line:

```
edgePoints[3] = edgePoint3;
```

Probably a typo.

gdb cannot fail before, because the previous line might have been a valid instruction, except for the wrong index. The failure happens after this execution, when some code to check the state of the stack is triggered (depends on your compiler flags, you didn't give them).

At this stage, an undefined behavior (the mentioned line) already wrecked havoc and anything can happen. Due to the checks, at least you see that you have a stack problem.

You can add more checks for out of bound access on some compilers or with address sanitizers. They would have flagged the error without relying on gdb.